# In x86 assembly how can you set the zero flag (ZF) without doing a compare operation?

Tags: x86, assembly, machine-code

I have a short piece of (x86) assembly that I am trying to figure out what it does.

```
...
 6:     81 ec 00 01 00 00       sub    $0x100, %esp
 c:     31 c9                   xor    %ecx  , %ecx
 e:     88 0c 0c                mov    %cl   , (%esp, %ecx, 1)
11:     fe c1                   inc    %cl
13:     75 f9                   jne    0xe
....
```

It looks like its looping though until the "JNE" evaluates to false, i.e. the zero flag = 0.  (possibly its putting the numbers 1, 2, 3 ... into the stack??)

From my short investigation into assembly (im new at this) it seam you set the zero flag by doing a compare operation (CMP), but I dont see a compare operation.

So, under what conditions will it break out of this loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`inc` sets ZF if the value of `cl` after the increment is zero.  Your loop is doing this:

```
sub    $0x100, %esp            // unsigned char array[256];
xor    %ecx  , %ecx            // unsigned char cl = 0;
mov    %cl   , (%esp, %ecx, 1) // e: array[cl] = cl;
inc    %cl                     //    cl += 1;
jne    0xe                     //    if (cl != 0) goto e;
```

The loop terminates when `cl` is incremented from 255 and wraps around to 0, setting ZF.

Comment: I think I followed all that except for `mov %cl, (%esp, %ecx, 1)`. In English I would say "move the lower 8 bits of CX (CL) into RAM at the address at ESP+ECX", which makes sense, but what is the `1` operand? Is this really `array[cl + 1] = cl` (stack overflow?) or maybe `array[cl] = cl + 1`? Probably I'm missing some nuance of x86 assembly, but I'm curious.

Comment: The 1 is actually a size by which to scale the offset.  So its really array[cl * 1] = cl.

Comment: @Mike: Note that it's just `mov [esp+ecx], cl` in Intel syntax.

Comment: @GreyCat, pedantically `[esp+1*ecx]` (with specifically no displacement, rather than disp8=0 or disp32=0), though it is not really ambiguous in this case since `esp` cannot be used as a index register.

Answer (score 10):

Arithmetic instructions such as `add, sub, inc, dec, sar, sal`, but also bitwise operations such as `test, shl, shr, or, and, xor, neg` and so on, modify the ZF.

Comment: Thanks for the complete list, it will be useful.  Did you get this from a particular reference or did you know it off hand?

Comment: I knew these instructions, but I had to look up the specific effects in the intel manuals / google. I don't know of a list of instructions affecting the ZF.

Answer (score 2):

math operations such as inc and dec can also set the zero flag.

Answer (score 1):

Or, for starters, save [push] the flags on stack, [pop] get the stack in register, use arithmatic or operator with desired bit on the register, push the register and pop in the flag.

something like this.

```
pushf
pop ax
or ax, 0x100 [this will set trap flag, you can get the value for any flag or flags you want]
push ax
popf
```